# Symfony2 - how to clear / edit a flash message

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig, flash-message

I am setting a flash message in my controller when rendering a twig template.
If there is a post action, I would like to redirect to the same page, but change the flash message.

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    ...
    ...

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->clear(); // Does not work
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->all();   // Does not work

    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set('user-notice', $flash_message2);

    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}


$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('user-notice', $flash_message1);

return $this->render(....
```

But the problem is that the displayed flash messages is the $flash_message1, and should be $flash_message2.

When trying to use add instead of set, I can see them both.
I tryied to use the Symfony2 `clear()` and `all()` functions: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBagInterface.html but nothing changed.

Any idea? Thank you !!!

Comment: could you please include the method's relevant code completely and maybe add how your attempt with `clear()` and `set()` looked?

Comment: `problem is that the displayed flash messages is the 1st one.` ... what message gets returned if you send a POST request?  ... $flash_message or $flash_message **2** ?

Comment: When using the post, flashMessage2 needs to be displayed, but instead of this one, the flashMessage1 is displayed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use...

```
$flashBag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
$flashBag->get('user-notice'); // gets message and clears type
$flashBag->set('user-notice', $flash_message2);
```

... after your `isPost()` condition.

Comment: Ahhh, I know what's the problem. When I am using redirect, I am redirecting to the same page, so even if I set the flashMessage2, an the end the flashMessage1 will be set because I am redirecting to the same page. Any idea on how to fix that ?

Comment: Thanks, but this did not fixed teh problem. The `$flashBag->has('user-notice')` is allwaays false.

Comment: have you cleared your cache and your browser cache ? Updated my answer - just use `get()` to clear the message. It has to be unset afterwards ... see [FlashBag Line 97](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Session/Flash/FlashBag.php#L97).

Comment: Yes, both caches are cleared. About your new answer, the problem is how to know if I have to set the 1st or 2nd message. In both cases, I am comming from an redirect, so not from post. Should I use a simple render instead of redirect ?

Answer (score 16):

To clear all flash messages use the following code:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->clear();
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? An explanation would help people like me, reading this, understand what's going on.

Comment: Upvoted, there's absolutely no reason this should be downvoted. The only thing to note is that this clears the ENTIRE flashbag and not a specific one like 'user-notice'.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to delete *all* flash messages is as follows:

```
// clear all messages from FlashBag
$flashBag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
foreach ($flashBag->keys() as $type) {
    $flashBag->set($type, array());
}
```

This works just fine in Symfony 2.4, and probably all other recent versions.

Comment: That is not easy! The easy way is this: `$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->clear();`

Comment: @Trix There used to be an issue with exactly what you suggested two years ago. Have another look at the question: Milos is asking what to do when it does not work that way.