# how to remove a flash bag message in shopware 6 cart

Tags: symfony, shopware6

Im working on a shopware project.

I have made some conditions.

when a combination is not met I trigger a notice using a flash bag

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

$this->flashBag->add(
                "info",
                "Invalid entry, You are trying to include a product with dropshipping option to a product without a dropshipping option."
            );
```

All is fine, but iv noticed that when I show this notice, there is also a default notice
which is thrown

**"product added to cart"**

I am trying to hide this **"product added to cart"**. notice, as it is produced using the same flash bag component.

I have tried using the set method available within the flashbaginterface

```
$this->flashBag->set("success", false);
```

but I am unable to get it removed,

how do I properly remove a flash bag notice in shopware 6?

**notice******

my question was initially closed because it was deemed to be a duplicate of this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072975/symfony2-how-to-clear-edit-a-flash-message`

but to be honest that solution on clears manual notices I have set through my subscriber and not the default one that is sent to the checkout page when I add an item