# how to remove or manipulate a notice message set by default in shopware 6 cart

Tags: shopware6

Notice: my initial question here was closed

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922270/how-to-remove-a-flash-bag-message-in-shopware-6-cart
```

because it was deemed to be a duplicate of this [Symfony2 - how to clear / edit a flash message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072975/symfony2-how-to-clear-edit-a-flash-message)

But to be honest that solution clears manually created notices only when called via subscriber and not the default one sent to the checkout page when I add an item.

I'm working on a shopware project. I have made some conditions.

When a combination is not met, I trigger a notice using a flash bag

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

$this->flashBag->add(
                "info",
                "Invalid entry, You are trying to include a product with dropshipping option to a product without a dropshipping option."
            );
```

All is fine, but iv noticed that when I show this notice, there is also a default notice which is thrown

"product added to cart"

I am trying to hide this "product added to cart".

[image: the notice]

I have tried using the set method available within the flashbaginterface

```
$this->flashBag->set("success", false);
```

and this too

```
$this->flashBag->clear();
```

but I am unable to get it removed,

how do I properly remove a default notice sent to my cart page in shopware 6?